# initialData in FutureBuilder - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

What is the purpose of `initialData` in `FutureBuilder`? The documentation says:-

> The data that will be used to create the snapshots provided until a non-null future has completed

Does that mean the placeholder data that gets shown to the user when the data is `await`ing?

If that was the case then why my FutureBuilder always shows the loading state and not the `initialData`

My `FutureBuilder()`

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: _getPosts(),
      initialData: _getOfflineData(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Post>> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData ||
            snapshot.data == null ||
            snapshot.data.isEmpty ||
            snapshot.hasError) {
          // Still loading || load null data UI
          return ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: [for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) HorizontalPostShimmer()],
          );
        }
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final titleExists = doesTitleExist(snapshot.data[index].title);
            final title = titleExists
                ? snapshot.data[index].title
                : _translate.translate('unknownTitle');
            final imgExists =
                doesImageExist(snapshot.data[index].featuredMedia);
            final img = imgExists ? snapshot.data[index].featuredMedia : null;
            return Container(
              width: 300.0,
              child: Card(
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                SAPost(data: snapshot.data[index]),
                            settings: RouteSettings(name: 'SAPost')));
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        img == null
                            ? Container(
                                child: SaviorImageShimmer(
                                height: 100,
                                width: 100,
                              ))
                            : CachedNetworkImage(
                                imageUrl: img,
                                placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                    SaviorImageShimmer(),
                                errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                    Icon(Icons.error),
                              ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              '$title',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: _isMobile ? 18.0 : 22.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    )
```

And my `_getPosts()`

```
Future<List<Post>> _getPosts() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> args = {
      'IDs': [1983],
      'perPage': 10,
      'pageNum': 1,
      'from': 'horizontalSlider'
    };

    final Future<List<Post>> posts =
        context.read(fetchSpecificPostsByCategoriesProvider(args).future);
    return posts;
  }
```

And my `_getOfflineData()`

```
List<Post> _getOfflineData() {
    final List<Post> cachedPosts =
        Hive.box('posts').get('horizontalSlider', defaultValue: <Post>[]);
    return cachedPosts;
  }
```

Am I doing something that my `FutureBuilder()` always returns the `ListView` about loading?
Or is `initialData` used in another way

Answer (score 0):

In case if you would like to provide some data while other data is being fetched, you can use the `initialData` property to provide that data.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is as clear as it can be. My guess is your initial data [is empty](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/isEmpty.html). Try removing the following condition from the `build` function and check again: `snapshot.data.isEmpty`.